# Invalid hook call. But I don't know why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**Hello!!**

I am making a web app in react and I am trying to make a video disappear after it's done playing, but I get a invalid hook call error , I used the same method once more in another script and it works there just fine. I need it to be a function and not a class.

```
        import './App.css';
        import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
        import Theanim from './AnimationPicker';
        import pullanim from './wishfinal';
       

      
export default Animation = (stars) => {
            const [displayed, setDisplayed] = useState()
            var anim = pullanim(stars);
            var Theanimation = Theanim(anim);
            return(
                <div>
                { displayed && Theanimation}
                
                <button className="closebutton" type="submit" outline onClick={() => setDisplayed(false)}>Close</button>
                
                
                </div>
            );
            
          }
```

Here is the animation / Theanim() code :

```
    export default function Theanim(anim) {

    return(
<div>
    
    <video autoPlay="autoplay" muted className='pullanimation'>
    <source src={anim} type="video/mp4" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>


</div>

    );

}
```

I will add the onEnded() function to the video after I solve this error.

I made sure to call the hook inside the function and also at the top, i do not get why it doesn't work it makes no sense to me, I have used the same method in another .js script as so and it works just fine  :

```
 const MyComponent = () => {
const [displayed, setDisplayed] = useState()

let button;

if(displayed == true){
    button = <button className="closebutton" type="submit" outline onClick={() => setDisplayed(false)}>Close</button>
}

return (
  <div>
    { displayed && <WishStick /> }
    <button id='buttonwish1' className='wishbuttonx1' type='submit'> <img className ='wishbuttonx1img' src={buttonx1} 
    outline onClick={() => setDisplayed(true)} /> </button>
    {button}
    
  </div>
)
```

}

Edit: Here's the entire error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YyGc.jpg

***If anyone could help me I would appreciate it immensely! Remember that I need it to be a function and not a class.***

Comment: Can you include the whole error message in the question?

Comment: Yeah sure : https://imgur.com/oH9hTlw , I also edited the post to include it.

Comment: In your code in the imgur link (which you didn't post in the question for some reason) you call `Animation` as a function (wishStick.render, line 16). You can't do that, that's why the call is invalid.

Comment: I have also tried having it as function Animation() {} and it still didn't work, it gave me the exact same error. https://imgur.com/CypNezi

Comment: @Navraz yes, that's because either way you're not *using it as a React component*, and you can *only call hooks inside of hooks or React components*.

Comment: Yeah you need to call `Animation` and (all other components) like this `<Animation/>`, not like this `Animation()`. The rendering of `Animation` was not included here, but based on the way you render `Theanim`, I'm guessing you do the same with `Animation`.

Comment: This is how I rendered it, the problem is if I call it as <Animation /> it won't use the variable stars , I have tried defining it in Animation but then it is not synchronised with WishResults, meaning Wish() will have different values, I hope it makes sense. :'( also thanks!
Edit: made it imgur link for better readability https://imgur.com/P9GF4XG

Comment: I guess I'll have to figure it out, thanks for answering, please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are completely missing the point on how react components work. Based on the screenshot with the error you posted you are calling the `useState` hook in the `Animation` component but when you are using that component you are using it like so `const animationP = Animation(stars)` which is a complete wrong way of using react components.

I'm gonna repost your code with slight adjustments to ilustrate how you should do it instead.

I want you to notice the way the props are passed when we are using `Theanim` component and the way Animation gets the stars value through props.

For more information you should [read here react docs on components and props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

```js
import "./App.css";
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import Theanim from "./AnimationPicker";
import pullanim from "./wishfinal";

const Animation = (props) => {
  const [displayed, setDisplayed] = useState();

  // if this is still a react component you should use it the same way as <Theanim anim={anim} />
  const anim = pullanim(props.stars);

  return (
    <div>
      {displayed && <Theanim anim={anim} />}

      <button className="closebutton" type="submit" outline onClick={() => setDisplayed(false)}>
        Close
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Animation;
```

```js
export default function Theanim(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <video autoPlay="autoplay" muted className="pullanimation">
        <source src={props.anim} type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}
```